# Chrome Extension for looking string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Need bit help to make a Chrome extension that looks for string `x` from the source and creates a popup if `x` has been found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's hard for us to help you with this sort of question because you haven't provided us much context, or what you've tried and are having difficulty with. Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2):

String containing the source of the document:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Check if it contains `x`:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf(x) !== -1;
```

Happy Coding!